# How many weddings has the Doctor had?

Tags: doctor-who

In the tenth Doctor episode "[Blink](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/29-10.htm)" the Doctor states:

> DOCTOR: Look, sorry, I've got a bit of a complex life. Things don't always happen to me in quite the right order. Gets a bit confusing at times, especially at weddings. I'm rubbish at weddings, **especially my own.**
>   <sub>emphasis mine</sub>

In the Doctor's timeline this episode happened before "The Wedding of River Song" implying that the Doctor has been married before.

How many weddings has the Doctor had and to whom?

Comment: Well there's Queen Elizabeth ( episode : Day of the Doctor). I don't remember any more from the modern series, there may be more from the classics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Doctor Who wiki](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Doctor) offers a pretty comprehensive overview of his married life according to the various TV series and prose books.

To date, he's **definitely** been married at least four times, excluding his relationship with River Song but only two of those marriages took place prior to "Blink".

In rough chronological order

- **Unnamed Galifreyan woman** (who may or may not be [Patience](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Patience_(Cold_Fusion)))
- [**Patience**](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Patience_(Cold_Fusion))
- [**Scarlette**](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Scarlette)
- [**Elizabeth I**](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Elizabeth_I)
- [**River Song**](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/River_Song)
- [**Marilyn Monroe**](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Marilyn_Monroe)

> *After Gallifrey was destroyed in the Second War in Heaven, the Eighth
>   Doctor married **[Scarlette](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Scarlette)** in order to ceremonially tie himself to the
>   planet Earth. (PROSE: The Adventuress of Henrietta Street)*
>
> *The Tenth Doctor romanced and later married **[Elizabeth I](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Elizabeth_I)**. (TV: The End
>   of Time, The Day of the Doctor) She later declared him an enemy after
>   he failed to return as promised. (TV: The Shakespeare Code) This did
>   not appear to be the Doctor's only marriage, as he remarked to Sally
>   Sparrow about being "rubbish at weddings, especially my own." (TV:
>   Blink) In his eleventh incarnation, the Doctor accidentally became
>   engaged to [**Marilyn Monroe**](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Marilyn_Monroe), and married her the same night in what he
>   later claimed was not a real chapel. (TV: A Christmas Carol)*

It's also worth mentioning that at some point before the events of the First Time War, the Doctor was almost certainly married to an unnamed Galifreyan woman and had several children.  He was also then married to another Galifreyan woman ([Patience](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Patience_(Cold_Fusion))) in his guise as the fifth Doctor.

Comment: So the eighth Doctor wedding is the only one that would have been likely to have happened prior to Blink?

Comment: @Xantec - Probably at least two other marriages before that.